# How to check for last loop when using for loop in php?

Tags: php, for-loop

How to check for last loop when using a for loop php ?

This is my code, But it not work.

```
$x = "10";
for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
    if ($i != '$x - 1') {
        echo "$i no last";
    } else {
        echo "$i last";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

When I test it's echo

```
0 last
1 no last
2 no last
3 no last
4 no last
5 no last
6 no last
7 no last
8 no last
9 no last
```

How can I make the code check for the last loop? Thank you.

Comment: `$i!='$x - 1'` is looking at the literal string $x - 1. Get rid of the single quotes around the expression, replace with brackets if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are other data types than strings in PHP. What you are doing is comparison of strings, not of actual numbers.

`$x = "10";` will not set `$x` to `10`, but to `"10"`, which is the string built of a one and a zero. This has not necessarily the numerical value 10.

Your comparison then takes this string and compares it to the loop's counter variable using the expression `'$x - 1'`. This is the most significant thing here. PHP does not replace variables in single-quoted strings. Here is an example for comparison:

```
$foo = 42;
echo '$foo Bar'; // Output: $foo Bar
echo "$foo Bar"; // Output: 42 Bar
```

So, basically what your `if` condition does is to check if your loop's counter is not equal `'$x - 1'`. Comparing strings works completely differently than comparing numbers and in this case it does not at all what you intended anyway. (Especially because PHP's equality (`==`) and inequality operator (`!=`) sometimes behave really unexpectedly, if you're not familiar with types.)

Accidentally PHP tries to help you as much as it can, which is why your `for` loop works. In there you compare a number to a string. That makes not sense, but PHP makes it work for you. ;)

Just use everything as numerical values without the string notation:

```
<?php
$x = 10;
for($i=0; $i < $x; $i++)
{
    if($i != ($x - 1)) {
        echo $i."no last";
    } else {
        echo $i."last";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: +1 though just removing the quotes would have done the trick as PHP would have type cast the $x to 10. Just a side note. ;)

Comment: Sure. Doesn't mike it right, though. And I wouldn't respond to a question where basically just a typo causes the issue. Enough people are doing that "job". ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you should get required output

```
$x = "10";
for($i=0;$i<$x;$i++)
{
    if($i!= $x - 1 ) {
        echo $i."no last";
    } else if($i == $x - 1) {
        echo $i."last";
    }
    echo "<BR>";
}
```

Comment: Come on, at least _explain_ what change you made instead of just "here you go".

Comment: removed the single quote in `if()`

Comment: _In the answer_. Also, you removed 2 single quotes. Finally, you did that, because?

Comment: i didnt notice that part, i was seeing else part and added condition, when i was running, i noticed that and removed the quotes.