# How to get last iteration of for loop when limit and increment is dynamic?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, logic

I have seen some question related to this one like

[How to check for last loop when using for loop in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32869997/how-to-check-for-last-loop-when-using-for-loop-in-php)

[Last iteration of enhanced for loop in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285523/last-iteration-of-for-loop-in-java)

but I am not getting exact solution because in my case **increment** and **end limit** both are **dynamic**.

**Requirement:-** I do not want comma after last element printed.

```
$inc=11;
$end=100;
for($i=1;$i<=$end;$i=$i+$inc){
    echo $i==$end?$i:"$i,";  // 1,12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,100
}
```

In above code I know that *last element($i)* will be *100($end)*.

So I can write condition as **$i==$end** but in below case it won't work.

```
$inc=12;  // Now $inc is 12
$end=100;
for($i=1;$i<=$end;$i=$i+$inc){
    echo $i==$end?$i:"$i,";  // 1,13,25,37,49,61,73,85,97,
}
```

Now last element 97 has comma which I need to remove.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it critical to use for loop instead of while(condition)?

Comment: You can just check if the next iteration with the increment will run or not: `echo $i + $inc >$end?$i:"$i,";`

Comment: Why don't you just make an array of the incremented elements and then use implode function with comma as a glue? you wouldn't have to worry about any of this if you use implode instead.

Comment: @Rizier123: Thanks brother. It is working like a charm :-)

Comment: @LauriOrgla: I am already in loop so it is not a good idea to store all elements in array and then use implode.

Comment: @RaviHirani If you had gazillion items, then yes. But your example shows from 1 to 100. You wanted working solution, i gave you one. Otherwise you would have to determine in the loop whether the element you are working with is the last one. If not, then append a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use,

```
echo $i+$inc>$end?$i:"$i,";
```

It checks whether this is the last possible iteration instead.

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple:

```
$numbers = range(0, $end, $inc);
$string = implode(",", $numbers);
echo $string;
```

You can see it here: https://3v4l.org/BRpnH

;)

Comment: Good alternative. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use rtrim to remove the last comma

```
$inc   = 12;  // Now $inc is 12
$end   = 100;

$print = '';
for($i=1;$i<=$end;$i=$i+$inc){
    $print .= ($i==$end)? $i : "$i,";  // 1,13,25,37,49,61,73,85,97,
} 
$print = rtrim($print, ',');
echo $print;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way :

```
<?php
$inc=4;
$end=10;
for($i=1;$i<=$end;$i=$i+$inc){
    echo ($i+$inc-1)>=$end?$i:"$i,";  // 1,5,9
} 
?>
```

This code is working on prime number case also not given you result like `// 1,13,25,37,49,61,73,85,97,` always gives you result like `// 1,13,25,37,49,61,73,85,97` no comma added after any prime number.